# PostgreSQL: How to automatically set table owner when creating new table

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, table owner is automatically set to user who created the table when creating new table. In this situation, the other users can not dropped the table.

So I want to automatically change table owner for newly created tables to specific role. By using this approach, anyone who has this role can drop the tables which table owner is the same role.

To achieve this goal, I used the same approach as described in this blog. https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/

I am currently using this function. This function should be triggered when new table is created in a schema `analytics_custom` and change table owner to `analytics_custom_readwrite`.
But it looks like the functions is not working as expected. Table owner of newly created table is an user who created the table.

Am I missing something? Any problem with this function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION analytics_custom.trg_create_set_owner()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN
        SELECT *
        FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
        WHERE schema_name='analytics_custom' AND command_tag='CREATE TABLE'
    LOOP
        if obj.object_identity ~ 'analytics_custom.*'
        THEN
            EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO analytics_custom_readwrite', obj.object_identity);
        end if;
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$
;
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER analytics_custom_trg_create_set_owner
    ON ddl_command_end
    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE')
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE analytics_custom.trg_create_set_owner();
```

Comment: You are missing the `CREATE EVENT TRIGGER` statement.